# Can i return more than 1 value from databricks notebook in a single command?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

I have a set of values to return as output from my databricks notebook. Can anyone sugggest a way to do that in an efficient and easy way?

Answer (score 0):

You can only export a string, but you can organize its content as you want. You could export a JSON as a string, containing your different values. The output is then parsed to.retrieve the different values.

Answer (score 0):

You could run said notebook within your current notebook using: `%run <path to your notebook>`. This will, however, import all variables etc from that notebook.